# ON OFF by the generated button does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using CSS and Javascript.
I'm trying to generate a toggle button to switch the brightness.

Why can't the code below switch styles?

◆ Toggle button Javascript ◆

```js
//---------- javascript ----------//
// Generate toggle button element
window.addEventListener('load', l => {
  document.querySelector("body")
    .insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `
<div class="L_D_switch" id="makeImg2" >
  <input type="checkbox" id="L_D_check" checked="" />
    <label for="L_D_check" onclick="Light_dark_Switch()" >
      <span></span>
    </label>
</div>
`);
  //  </label> //  checked="" //onclick="Light_dark_Switch()"
});


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Switching (processing) setting when the toggle button is pressed
function Light_dark_Switch() {
  let _css = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
  let html = document.documentElement;

  // if( ( Number % 2 ) !== 0 ) {
  if (!(_css.textContent).length) {
    // if( _css.textContent !== null ){
    // if(_css.style.display=="none"){
    // _css.textContent.style.display = "block";
    _css.textContent = `
html{
filter: sepia(25%) brightness(90%);
}
body{
background-color:#F9F9F9;
}
`;
    document.head.appendChild(_css);
    // _css.disabled = true;
    // _css.disabled = false;
    // html.classList.toggle(_css);
    // }

  } else
    // if (Number % 2 === 0) {
    if ((_css.textContent).length) {
      // if( _css.textContent % 2 === 0){
      // if( _css.textContent !== null ){
      // _css.textContent = null;
      // if(_css.style.display=="block"){
      // _css.textContent.style.display = "none";
      document.head.removeChild(_css);
      _css.textContent = undefined;
      // }
    }
}
```

◆Toggle button CSS ◆

```css
/*------------ CSS -----------*/

.L_D_switch {
  zoom: 45%;
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  position: fixed;
}

.L_D_switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.L_D_switch label {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 45px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #78bd78;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #888;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #600;
  color: #fbff01;
}

.L_D_switch label span:after {
  content: "on";
  /*  color          : #aaa;*/
  background: #eee;
}

.L_D_switch #L_D_check:checked+label {
  background: #eee;
  /*  box-shadow     : none;       */      
}
.L_D_switch #L_D_check:checked + label span:after {
  content        : "off";               
  color       :#9a9a9a;/*   : #fff;     */   
             
}


.L_D_switch:active{
height: 48px;
margin-top: -2px;
transition: none;
}
```

When switching by key down, you can switch with the above capacity, but you can not switch in the same way.

Why can't I switch? What am I missing?

please tell me.

```js
// Successful switching of key events
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let css = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) { // CTRL+F11
      if (!css.textContent) {
        css.textContent = `
html{
filter: sepia(25%) brightness(90%);
}
body{
background-color:#F9F9F9;
}
`;
        document.head.appendChild(css);
      } else {
        if (css.textContent) {
          document.head.removeChild(css);
          css.textContent = undefined;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: My guess is that its not working because you've commented out all of your HTML.

Comment: wait, will setting a css tag on display:none deactivate the styles? didnt know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple way you can do this that move `onclick="Light_dark_Switch(this)"` to check box. Get check box value inside `Light_dark_Switch` and add CSS per your need to HTML and Body using javascipt `getElementsByTagName`.

**Check the below snippet.**

```
//---------- javascript ----------//
// Generate toggle button element
window.addEventListener('load', l => {
    document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `
        <div class="L_D_switch" id="makeImg2" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="L_D_check" checked="" onclick="Light_dark_Switch(this)" />
            <label for="L_D_check"  >
            <span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    `);
    //  </label> //  checked="" //onclick="Light_dark_Switch()"
});

// Switching (processing) setting when the toggle button is pressed
function Light_dark_Switch(cb) {
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('#L_D_check').value;
    if( !cb.checked ){
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.filter = "sepia(25%) brightness(90%)";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F9F9F9";     
    }else{
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.filter = "";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "";    
    }
}
```

and for `e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122` you can simply trigger checkbox by using `click()`.

```
// Successful switching of key events
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) { // CTRL+F11
            var link = document.getElementById('L_D_check');
            link.click();
        }
    });
});
```

```js
//---------- javascript ----------//
// Generate toggle button element
window.addEventListener('load', l => {
    document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `
        <div class="L_D_switch" id="makeImg2" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="L_D_check" checked="" onclick="Light_dark_Switch(this)" />
            <label for="L_D_check"  >
            <span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    `);
    //  </label> //  checked="" //onclick="Light_dark_Switch()"
});

// Switching (processing) setting when the toggle button is pressed
function Light_dark_Switch(cb) {
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('#L_D_check').value;
    if( !cb.checked ){
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.filter = "sepia(25%) brightness(90%)";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F9F9F9";     
    }else{
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.filter = "";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "";    
    }
}

// Successful switching of key events
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) { // CTRL+F11
            var link = document.getElementById('L_D_check');
            link.click();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/*------------ CSS -----------*/

.L_D_switch {
  zoom: 45%;
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  position: fixed;
}

.L_D_switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.L_D_switch label {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 45px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #78bd78;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #888;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #600;
  color: #fbff01;
}

.L_D_switch label span:after {
  content: "on";
  /*  color          : #aaa;*/
  background: #eee;
}

.L_D_switch #L_D_check:checked+label {
  background: #eee;
  /*  box-shadow     : none;       */      
}
.L_D_switch #L_D_check:checked + label span:after {
  content        : "off";               
  color       :#9a9a9a;/*   : #fff;     */   
             
}


.L_D_switch:active{
height: 48px;
margin-top: -2px;
transition: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer.

It seems that there was an embarrassing mistake

.L_D_switch label span:after{
, background : #eee;
I forgot to turn it off.

Thanks to the respondents, it has evolved into a splendid function.

Comment: Welcome... Glad to be of help.